# Use of 'supposed to' with was

Tags: past-tense

I have an exercise in my grammar book which deals with use of 'supposed to'.

My teacher told me that 'supposed to' can not be used with was except am/is/are.

> "I was supposed to meet you at 9."

Isn't above sentence grammatically correct?

I think I have heard people using 'was supposed to'. Who is grammatically correct?

Comment: A reputable dictionary is your best friend. _No one was supposed to know about it._
_The meeting was supposed to take place on Tuesday, but we’ve had to postpone it._

Comment: I would ask the teacher for a thorough explanation. Adding such detail would make this a better question.

Answer (score 2):

> I was supposed to meet you at 9.

Is absolutely grammatical.

I would assume the teacher indicated some specific circumstances about when to use the present or the past, and maybe for the exercise at hand, you were not supposed to<sup>(*)</sup> use the past tense. As a *general* rule, it makes no sense to claim the past cannot be used.

---

<sup>(*)</sup><sub>see what I did there?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You and your teacher are both correct.

In the *simple present* tense, *supposed to* can only be used with "is/am/are."

But you are correct that in the *simple past* tense, *supposed to* can be used with "was," and also "were":

You/they were supposed to meet me at 9.